# How can I install a particular version of a conda package?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, grib, eccodes

I am trying to install the v2.7.0 of the `eccodes` package.

But this is not working:

`conda install -c conda-forge eccodes=2.7.0`

I can see the versions here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eccodes/files?version=2.7.0&page=2

What I am doing wrong with the syntax?

The latest version is 2.13, which I don't want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look through all of the package versions on the first page, you will notice that their label is 'main'. However, the version you want to install has the label 'cf201901'.

You should therefore change your install command to:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 eccodes=2.7.0
```

By including the label in the channel it will be able to find the correct older version.

Alternatively, you can copy the link of the old package directly from the website you were browsing and just run:

```
conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eccodes/2.7.0/download/osx-64/eccodes-2.7.0-0.tar.bz2
```

If you want to install version 2.7.0 for osx