# conda install package of old version

Tags: conda

I want to install an old version of keras (1.2.2), which I cannot find using `conda search -c conda-forge keras`. However, I was able to find it in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras/files?version=1.2.2&page=4. I didn't know how to get it though.

I did realize there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405268/how-can-i-install-a-particular-version-of-a-conda-package) on stackoverflow but the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> but the solution didn't work for me.

What didn't work?

`conda install python=3.6 keras=1.2.2 -c conda-forge` works for me right out of the box. If you **really** want to target an older version of Python, you can do that as well. It looks like that channel has builds for 2.7 and 3.5 as well.

It's worth pointing out that installing old versions of research software is generally unadvisable.

Comment: I used this command:
conda install -c conda-forge keras=1.2.2

And I got:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - keras=1.2.2
(because there is a character limit for the comment, the output was trimmed)

For the unadvisable problem, th new keras implement merge layer differently than the codes from a 2017 paper that I need to run, what should I do?